# Апплет в браузере не работает

Tags: jquery, applet, javascript, java

Доброго времени суток. Друзья, помогите решить проблему. 
Пишу апплет для коннекта со скайпом. Сам коннект осуществляется через библиотеки `dll`.(Локально всё работает отлично). Если запустить апплет в отладке из `IDE`, то коннект проходит успешно и можно выполнять манипуляции со скайпом. Но если я помещаю апплет на страницу html, то при попытке обращения к методу апплета вылетает ошибка

```
Uncaught Error:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionjs.js:4 
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

Код метода, который обращается к скайпу.

```
public String foo() throws SkypeException {
    return Skype.getContactList().getAllGroups().toString();
}
```

Код js, в котором функция `show` обращается к методу апплета `foo()`

```
var applet;

function show(){
    alert(applet.foo())
}

jQuery(function(){
    applet = $("#applet")[0]
})
```

Апплет подписан ключом.

Буду премного благодарен за любое оказание помощи.

Comment: страница естественно размещена где то в интернете?

Comment: Пока нет, просто запустил html файл в браузере.

Comment: может по той причине, что оно запускается в песочнице?

Comment: Но когда запускаю аплет из ide, то всё отлично работает. А что ему может не хватать при работе с браузера?

Comment: может ide выставляет какие то переменные окружения или подстраивает браузер (например, запускает его с нужным родительским каталогом).